# PG - Select a record not reserved yet

Tags: postgresql

I have a PG (12) database with two tables:

RESERVABLES

```
id               uuid
```

RESERVATIONS

```
id               uuid
reservable_id    uuid
reserved_between tsrange
```

Where `reservations.reservable_id` is a foreign key on `reservables`.

Now, given a `tsrange` (i.e. `[2020-02-01 14:30, 2020-02-01 15:30]`) I need to find a `Reservable` not reserved yet for that time interval. However, I have no idea how to proceed.

A big plus would be to find the `Reservable` with the most free time (fewer reservations) for that date.

Answer (score 0):

This is my (untested) query:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM reservables AS p
   LEFT JOIN reservations AS c
      ON p.id = c.reservable_id
         AND NOT c.reserved_between
                 && tsrange('2020-02-01 14:30', '2020-02-01 15:30', '[]')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM reservations AS s
                  WHERE p.id = s.reservable_id
                  AND s.reserved_between
                      && tsrange('2020-02-01 14:30', '2020-02-01 15:30', '[]'))
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY count(c.id) NULLS FIRST
LIMIT 1;
```

The important part is the `NOT EXISTS` condition, the left outer join, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are just to collect the big plus. If the performance is not good enough, go for the simpler query.